# How can i input password from bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I am creating a bash script that trying to connect to a remote server, but it requires to enter a password, I wrote the following script:

ssh HostIP
expect "password:"
send "password"

but it connects and gives "user@HostIP's password:", so the send command is not writing any password to the screen....what should I do to make it work?

Comment: I think you should generate a RSA on your machine (id_rsa) and publish your public key to your server (id_rsa.pub). This will avoid you to provide password in clear to the server.

Comment: @Newmips, I think I too explained the same thing in answer :) Let's see what OP does on this, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Writing passwords in file(s) or scripts is NEVER a good practice. Why don't you give a try to password less authentication from one server to another.

***Simple steps:***

I- generate the RSA public and private keys from command `ssh -keygen -t rsa` to your server1.

II- Now create `.ssh` directory in your another server(server2)'s home dorectory with correct permissions.

III- Create file named `authorized_keys` on server2.

IV- Open file named `authorized_keys` on server2 and copy file named `id_rsa.pub` from server1 to server2.

V- Set permissions to 640 to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` now.

VI- try to login to server2 now by doing:

```
ssh user@server2
```

Here is a nice link which could tell you about same too.

https://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/

Once passwordless authentication is set from server1 to server2 with `ssh` then you could simply execute all `ssh` commands in your script which you want to run on another server.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with **sshpass** like :

```
sshpass -p **your_password**  ssh user@HostIP
```

If sshpass is not already installed, you can install it and make the first connection in bash console for "the yes confirmation"

Comment: Recommend `pass` [https://www.passwordstore.org/], using with encrypted password.